# Failure to render B64encoded Thymeleaf

Tags: image, base64, thymeleaf

I have searched many hours on here and across the Internet an am unable to render a properly B64 encoded image in an object.  I have tried every permutation of diacriticals and nothing.  Can someone inform the correct

```
            <tr th:each="re:${reorderList}">
                <td th:text="${re.invoiceNum}"></td>
                <td th:text="${re.ordered}"></td>
                <td th:text="${re.shipped}"></td>
                <td th:text="${re.sku}"></td>
                <td ><img th:src="${'data:image/jpg;base64,'+ re.upc_s" ></td>
                <td th:text="${re.upc01_s}"></td>
                <td th:text="${re.brand}"></td>
                <td th:text="${re.desc}"></td>
                <td th:text="${re.stdCost}"></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the ending curly brace in the `th:src` attribute of your `<img />` tag.  The expression should be:

```
th:src="${'data:image/jpg;base64,'+ re.upc_s}"
```

I would personally represent this as:

```
<img th:src="|data:image/jpg;base64, ${re.upc_s}|" />
```

Comment: Thank you.  Where is the documentation of the "|" also is there someplace succinct that distinguishes between the use of $,@,*

Comment: @cp. - There is a summary here: [Standard Expression Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax). Later sections provide additional details and examples.